# Why is the cookies not sent along with the request initiated by fetch(url, {credentials: 'include'})?

Tags: javascript, http, cookies, fetch-api

I manually set up a cookie at Google.ca using `document.cookie = 'foo=bar’`, which is a non http-only , not same-site and not secure cookie!

[image]

I then open up another tab and visit a **different** site `bing.com` and use `fetch` to send out a get request to google.ca with `credentials` option set to `include`:

```js
fetch('https://www.google.ca/', {credentials: 'include'}).then(console.log)
```

I expected this request would bring the cookies set under `google.ca` which should include `foo=bar` since I addd `credentials: 'include'` . Of course this is a cross origin request but according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch), `credentials: 'include'` tells browsers to include credentials in both same- and **cross-origin requests.**

However I didn’t see any cookies included in the request from the network tab. I wonder if I am missing something here? Or I completely misunderstood how cookies work?

Comment: The default value for the `SameSite` cookie attribute is now `Lax` in Chromium browsers. Such cookies are not attached to cross-origin requests that are not top-level navigations; your `fetch` request is like that.

Comment: @jub0bs oh got it. so if I explicitly set it to `None` then the cookies should get sent along with `fetch` + `credentials: 'include'`?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Comment: @jub0bs I just tried to `document.cookies = 'foo=bar; SameSite=None'` but still couldn't find the cookies being sent along. Maybe it is just now showing up in Chrome dev tool?

Comment: `SameSite=None` also requires `Secure`; otherwise, Chromium browsers won't set the cookie in question.